# Loop through sheets and add values to Dropdown list - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, dropdown

**Goal**

I would like to loop through five sheets and populate a dropdown list in a sixth sheet based on some requirements.

**Problem**

I don't know how to populate the dropdown list, make them dynamic and loop through the five sheets.

**Description**

In the sixth sheet (Dropdown Sheet), column E contains names which I would like to compare to the first row (E1:GG1) in the five sheets. Each column has a bunch of 1's.

If there is a match between a name in column E (Dropdown Sheet) and a name in a row (one of the five sheets) AND there's a '1' in the column for that row, the dropdown list should be populated with the ID in column A.

**Desired output**

[image]

[image]

**Code**

```
Private Sub ValuesInDropdownList()

    Dim TeamSource As Range, PersonSource As Range, r As Range, csString As String
    Dim PersonCell As Range, TeamCell As Range
    Dim Dropdown As Collection
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer

    Set TeamSource = Sheets("Dropdown Sheet").Range("E10:E100")
    Set PersonSource = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E1:GG1")
    Set Dropdown = New Collection

    On Error Resume Next

        For Each PersonCell In PersonSource
            v = PersonCell.Value
            Debug.Print (v)
            With PersonSource
                lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, PersonCell.Columns.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Debug.Print (lastRow)
            End With
                If v <> "" Then
                    For Each TeamCell In TeamSource
                        Debug.Print (TeamCell)
                        If PersonCell = TeamCell Then
                        intValueToFind = 1
                            For i = 1 To lastRow
                                If PersonCell.Offset(i, 0) = intValueToFind Then
                                Debug.Print (PersonCell.Offset(i, -4))
                                    Dropdown.Add v, CStr(v)
                                End If
                            Next i
                        End If
                    Next TeamCell
                End If
        Next PersonCell

End Sub
```

Comment: 1) E1 to G1 i think you mean. 2) Why is dropdown a collection? Do you actually mean a combobox or a listbox etc? Or is this a data validation list?  3) Should there be three of these? One for each team. Sorry if i have misunderstood.

Comment: You can loop the three columns populating separate arrays if 1 is present in column with value that is offset appropriate number of columns to left. You can then use these arrays to populate lists. For example, if you are doing data validation you can create the validation list using  .Add Type:=xlValidateList, Formula1:=Join(myArray, ",") . See here: http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?26528-Drop-down-validation-using-array

Comment: I actually mean GG1 :) The three teams are just an example. There is data up till GG1. You're right, I mean a combobox. Not sure what you mean by data validation list.

Comment: Is there a total number of possible teams or can it vary? Likewise, is there a set number of possible ids and are they always present?

Comment: If using arrays than add an Is in array test before adding items to ensure unique ids stored.

Comment: I'll explore the ListFillRange property. The teams in the Dropdown sheet will typically be the same as the ones in the individual sheets but they can vary. The number of ID's vary across the five individual sheets and the 1's don't follow a specific pattern.

Comment: I didn't answer question 2) from the first comment correctly. The dropdown list I want to apply is a "In-cell dropdown" similar to the one found in the Data Validation settings.

Comment: Then my second comment holds true. Are there fixed numbers of teams and ids?

Comment: Nope. Number of teams and ID's vary across individual sheets.

Comment: I mean... is there a maximum number of teams or ids or does one always have to loop all sheets to collect all possible entries?

Comment: I have to loop across all sheets because the number of teams and ID's vary. I think I have a solution ready. The looping across sheets causes some problems. Should I create a new post with the revised code?